# How can I automate Angularjs Protractor tests?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I've been trying to automate my Protractor tests for a couple weeks, and I've had many problems.  First I tried running them through Jenkins, which is installed on an Amazon Linux AMI instance.  That didn't work, because I couldn't properly install Firefox or Chrome, and I couldn't get PhantomJS to run my tests correctly.

Next I tried using SSH commands to get Jenkins to run the Protractor tests on a separate Ubuntu Server instance. Whenever I try to run Firefox or Chrome in there with Xvfb, it gets stuck on the step `Initializing built-in extension GLX`.  I also get the error `(process:7476): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed` when trying to run Firefox.

Any ideas that could point me in the right direction? I basically need to get Firefox or Chrome to run properly on either Amazon Linux AMI or Ubuntu Server 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

I use a headless selenium server in the cloud, it provides Chrome & Firefox even though there is no real DISPLAY. I've just moved the config files here: https://github.com/elgalu/headless

Works ok with Ubuntu Server 14.04.